# Can't understand SecurityManager.IsGranted()

Tags: c#

I intentionally reduced the permission for a method to see whether IsGranted method works, but it doesn't. Here's my code:

```
[FileIOPermission(SecurityAction.Deny, Read = "d:\\faz.txt")]
void aMethod()
{
  Console.WriteLine(SecurityManager.IsGranted(new 
    FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read,"d:\\faz.txt")));

}
```

The method returns true even if the method never given that permission. Can some one please explain about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you are using it correctly. You need to NOT create a new instance of FileIOPermission and use the one applied to the method.

Which leads to another issue. If your security is working correctly, how can that method execute?

Comment: Your answer is not clear. Can you please tell me at what situation IsGranted method should be used?

Comment: @fazxclusive: You retrieve the instance of the attribute on the method via reflection.